# trying to add certificates to my post method in java

Tags: java, file, ssl, crt

Hi im trying to add a crt and a key file to my post method as im using ssl connection to connect to server in https protocol

I dont know how to add crt and key and my server password to my request .

And also i use those certificates in my postman in setting/Client Certificates area

```
public static  GetAPI(String query_url) {

    int ResponseCode = -1;
    try {

        URL url = new URL(query_url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        // con.setDoOutput(true);
        // con.setDoInput(true);
        ResponseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
        String result = IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
        // System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
        // System.out.println(result);
        // System.out.println("result after Reading JSON Response");
        // JSONObject myResponse = new JSONObject(result);
        // System.out.println("jsonrpc- "+myResponse.getString("jsonrpc"));

        in.close();
        con.disconnect();

        return 

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);


    }
```

Comment: i need to add a .crt , .key and server password

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your case correctly, I think you need to add server certificate to your jre.
Take a look at [this post](https://medium.com/@codebyamir/the-java-developers-guide-to-ssl-certificates-b78142b3a0fc).

Comment: So i need to add the certs to my  machine env variables?

Comment: Not, they have to be added to your jre. Using keytool utility (shipped with jdk ), you must add your certificate to a file ($JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts) called truststore.